# Python file runs, but is not found. Er?

Tags: python

Symptoms: File is apparently being used:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/renderers/pyobjects.py", line 449, in render
  exec final_template in _globals, _locals
File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/pyobjects.py", line 293, in __getattr__
  raise AttributeError
```

Great. However when I go to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/pyobjects.py` it isn't in that directory and none of its pyc's are there either:

```
ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/py*
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/pydsl.py  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/pydsl.pyc
```

Why is this happening? What am I missing about this -- I have tried searching and found nothing useful yet.

Update if this is any use:

```
$ python -v
>>> import salt.utils.pyobjects
# /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/pyobjects.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/pyobjects.py
import salt.utils.pyobjects # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/pyobjects.pyc
```

Comment: you are running it in salt/renderers/pyobjects.py` whereas you are looking into salt/utils/pyobjects.py

Comment: Perhaps the `.pyc` file was moved elsewhere and that is now being imported, but the file recorded a full-path filename?. Run `python -v` and trace all imports.

Comment: @ha9u63ar: they are talking about the last line in the traceback.

Comment: You can *only* get the verbose output if *at the time of import* that file *actually exists*. So when that import takes place, **both files** are there, both `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/pyobjects.pyc` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/pyobjects.py` exist according to the OS and have a modification time and can be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `python -v` verbose output you posted shows that the file is imported from a different location:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/pyobjects.pyc
#    ^^^^^
```

but you are looking in:

```
ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/py*
#      ^^^^
```

`.pyc` files store a filename in the bytecode, and the file must've been moved from `/usr/lib` to `/usr/local/lib`. So when a traceback is shown, the filename from the bytecode is still pointing to the old location.

You can force a re-compile (running with `sudo` or another means to gain write access) with:

```
python -m compileall -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt
```

to produce `.pyc` files that store the new location.